# Univariate cox regression analysis with multiple covariates

Tags: regression, cox

```
covariates <- c("age", "sex",  "ph.karno", "ph.ecog", "wt.loss")
univ_formulas <- sapply(covariates,
                    function(x) as.formula(paste('Surv(time, status)~', x)))
                   
univ_models <- lapply( univ_formulas, function(x){coxph(x, data = lung)})
# Extract data 
univ_results <- lapply(univ_models,
                   function(x){ 
                      x <- summary(x)
                      p.value<-signif(x$wald["pvalue"], digits=2)
                      wald.test<-signif(x$wald["test"], digits=2)
                      beta<-signif(x$coef[1], digits=2);#coeficient beta
                      HR <-signif(x$coef[2], digits=2);#exp(beta)
                      HR.confint.lower <- signif(x$conf.int[,"lower .95"], 2)
                      HR.confint.upper <- signif(x$conf.int[,"upper .95"],2)
                      HR <- paste0(HR, " (", 
                                   HR.confint.lower, "-", HR.confint.upper, ")")
                      res<-c(beta, HR, wald.test, p.value)
                      names(res)<-c("beta", "HR (95% CI for HR)", "wald.test", 
                                    "p.value")
                      return(res)
                      #return(exp(cbind(coef(x),confint(x))))
                     })
res <- t(as.data.frame(univ_results, check.names = FALSE))
as.data.frame(res)
```

Normally I use this code for univariate cox regression analysis but I have multiple genes >20000 that I want to run as independent variables in a univariate cox regression analysis and I am not sure how I can run this code without typing the individual covariates (gene names) out. All my column names for the genes begin with "ENSG..".

Is there a way to do univariate cox regression on so many genes in an efficient way please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make the list of variable names without typing them out. Probably one of the easiest is to use `names()` to get all of the variable names in the data, then remove `time` and `status` from that list (as well as any other variables you don't want to include). For example, for the `veteran` dataset:

```r
covariates <- names(survival::veteran)
covariates # Look at which names were detected
#> [1] "trt"      "celltype" "time"     "status"   "karno"    "diagtime" "age"     
#> [8] "prior"
covariates <- covariates[-which(covariates %in% c("time", "status"))]
covariates # Confirm time and status have been removed
#> [1] "trt"      "celltype" "karno"    "diagtime" "age"      "prior"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You could also programmatically create a list of names. For example:

```r
covariates <- sapply(1:10, FUN = function(x) paste0("ENSG.", x))
covariates
#>  [1] "ENSG.1"  "ENSG.2"  "ENSG.3"  "ENSG.4"  "ENSG.5"  "ENSG.6"  "ENSG.7" 
#>  [8] "ENSG.8"  "ENSG.9"  "ENSG.10"
```

This approach might be better if the naming is easy to program. If the gene names are irregular it might be more difficult.

As far as efficiency, I don't think much can be done to improve the overall runtime. The bulk of the runtime is doing the actually `coxph()` calculations. There are other questions/answers on the site about optimizing R code. If you want to pursue optimization I'd suggest looking through those, and then making a new question with a reproducible example if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

you already did it. If you check the univ_formula (like univ_formula[1], and so on), then you can see it contains each term (covariate) independently.

For you gene data, you can modify the covariates variable and the rest is same:

covariates <- rownames(df) # of your dataframe or columnanes(df) of your df; I hope the genes should be in your column names.

#The following will create (paste) formula variable containing formula and gene name:

univ_formulas <- sapply(covariates,
function(x) as.formula(paste('Surv(time, status)~', x)))

The rest is the same as you used to do.

There is one more package (geneSA; https://github.com/huynguyen250896/geneSA) that can also be used.